# PSQL (postgres or redshift) stored variable to prompt and write query to dynamic filename

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, psql

My adhoc workflow has me in the `psql` client often, so often that I define useful queries or settings changes in my `.psqlrc` file. I'm sharing the solution to this because there are few examples online and since you can't use newlines in a metacommand the syntax gets ugly and debugging took a long time.

#### Define a `psql` meta-command in a variable that prompts for sql file path and writes to a local file with a dynamic filename

- prompt for sql file to execute
- prompt for output filename prefix
- generate a dynamic output filename based on ISO reporting week

Here is a manual example of the steps I want to wrap into a `.pqslrc`-defined variable:

```sql
-- the following at psql prompt =>>

select 'file_prefix' || '_week_'
  || to_char(next_day(current_date - 1 - 7 * 1, 'sat') + 1,'iyyy-iw') 
  || '.txt'  report_filename;
┌──────────────────────────────┐
│       report_filename        │
├──────────────────────────────┤
│ file_prefix_week_2019-07.txt │
└──────────────────────────────┘

\out file_prefix_week_2019-07.txt

\a \pset footer off   -- no border or row count to output file

\i 'path/to/sql_file.sql'
-- now I have a text file of the output locally on my machine

\out \a \pset footer on

=>>
-- back to normal terminal output
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working solution that can be issued on the `psql` command line or appended to a `.psqlrc` and invoked from the `psql` prompt with the variable name:

```sql
-- newlines are included for readability but:
-- **remove all newlines when pasting to .psqlrc**

\set report '\\echo enter filename prefix:\\\\ \\prompt file_prefix \\\\
 \\echo enter sql file path:\\\\ \\prompt sql_file \\\\
 select :''file_prefix'' || ''_week_''
 || to_char(next_day(current_date - 1 - 7 * 1, ''sat'') + 1,''iyyy-iw'')
 || ''.txt''  report_filename \\gset \\\\
 \\pset footer off \\pset border 0 \\pset expanded off \\pset format unaligned \\\\
 \\out :report_filename \\\\
 \\i :sql_file \\\\ 
 \\out \\\\
 \\pset footer on  \\pset border 2 \\pset expanded auto
 \\pset format aligned \\pset linestyle unicode'
```

#### key points:

[**Postgres `psql` documentation** *current version*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

- **when copy/pasting remove all the newlines**
- the variable string cannot have newlines, just one long string
- the string is contained in single quotes `'`
- the symbol `\\` separates commands

  - the symbol `\` is escaped by doubling
  - therefore use `\\` for `\`, `\\\\` for `\\`
- single quotes within the string are escaped by doubling

  - therefore use `''` for `'` within the string
  - this counts for `:variables` that are strings as well
- `\gset` assigns the output of a query to a variable of the column name
- the `:sql_file` can include spaces, the variable gets stored as a text string that `\i` is able to parse without wrapping as `:''sql_file''`

#### relevant components in `.psqlrc`

```sql
-- .psqlrc
-- remove newlines from \set variable strings before pasting

\pset fieldsep '\t'
\set prompt_1 '%R%#> '
\set PROMPT1 :prompt_1

\set prompt_copyout 'copyout : : : copyout\n%R%#> '

-- helper variables
-- usage:
-- :copyout desired_output_filename
\set copyout '\\pset footer off \\pset border 0 \\pset expanded off
 \\pset format unaligned \\pset title \\pset null '''' 
 \\set PROMPT1 :prompt_copyout \\out '

-- usage to return to normal terminal output
-- :copyoff
\set copyoff '\\pset footer on  \\pset border 2 \\pset expanded auto
 \\pset format aligned \\pset title \\pset null ''[null]'' 
 \\set PROMPT1 :prompt_1 \\pset linestyle unicode \\out \\\\'
```

#### reformulated with helper variables

I switch between copying out to local text files and viewing sql output in the terminal screen, so my actual usage includes the following helpers:

```sql
-- again remove all newlines before pasting into .psqlrc
\set report '\\echo enter filename prefix:\\\\ \\prompt file_prefix \\\\
 \\echo enter sql file path:\\\\ \\prompt sql_file \\\\
 select :''file_prefix'' || ''_week_''
 || to_char(next_day(current_date - 1 - 7 * 1, ''sat'') + 1,''iyyy-iw'')
 || ''.txt''  report_filename \\gset \\\\
 :copyout :report_filename \\\\
 \\i :sql_file \\\\ 
 :copyoff'
```